# My react app doen't display any content after I deploy it on digital ocean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, build

I've successfully deployed my react app on digital ocean as a static site. But when I click to see the live app the link only shows me a blank page, instead of show me the landing page (dashboard).

The command I used for the build
`npm build`

The code in my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import RTL from "layouts/RTL.js";

import "assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.9.0";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Route path="/rtl" component={RTL} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

my project structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL2Yi.png

Comment: try running `npm run build` and check if build folder exists thereafter before deploying again(do check for spaces in the name of the folder build, I got stuck once on it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to edit the package.json file and change the homepage attribute like this:

```
    "homepage": ""
```